# scalaXB Async Dispatcher java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop

Tags: scala, scalaxb

I am using ScalaXB to make a call to a SOAP Web Service. I generated the code against WSDL using the following command

I am making a call to the web service in a loop. I notice that the code runs fine for sometime but then starts throwing the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:68)
        at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:50)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:70)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:65)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:56)
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.ChannelManager.<init>(ChannelManager.java:173)
        at org.asynchttpclient.DefaultAsyncHttpClient.<init>(DefaultAsyncHttpClient.java:85)
        at dispatch.Http.client$lzycompute(execution.scala:16)
        at dispatch.Http.client(execution.scala:16)
        at dispatch.Http.client(execution.scala:11)
        at dispatch.HttpExecutor$class.apply(execution.scala:120)
        at dispatch.Http.apply(execution.scala:11)
        at dispatch.HttpExecutor$class.apply(execution.scala:115)
        at dispatch.Http.apply(execution.scala:11)
        at scalaxb.DispatchHttpClientsAsync$DispatchHttpClient$class.request(httpclients_dispatch_async.scala:22)
        at scalaxb.DispatchHttpClientsAsync$$anon$1.request(httpclients_dispatch_async.scala:7)
        at scalaxb.SoapClientsAsync$SoapClientAsync$class.soapRequest(soap12_async.scala:43)
        at scalaxb.SoapClientsAsync$$anon$1.soapRequest(soap12_async.scala:24)
        at scalaxb.SoapClientsAsync$SoapClientAsync$class.requestResponse(soap12_async.scala:63)
        at scalaxb.SoapClientsAsync$$anon$1.requestResponse(soap12_async.scala:24)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:176)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:150)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:103)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:64)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files in system
        at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.init(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.<init>(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:98)
        at sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.<init>(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:88)
        at sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorProvider.openSelector(KQueueSelectorProvider.java:42)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:174)
        ... 37 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the answer to this question. The problem was that I was doing a new on the proxy object inside of the loop.

It seems that these objects create a new connection and don't get cleaned up resulting in the error above.

I moved the proxy object out of the loop and just called the webservice inside the loop and the problem got resolved.